# Make text always stick at bottom of image for responsive site

Tags: html, css

I have a small div under each image that I need to be exactly at the bottom of the image also when my site is viewed on small devices. My whole site is in Bootstrap-3 already, but now my current code shows the small div called DATA half way over the image when viewed on smaller devices.

Two issues:
1 - How to make the div (data) have the responsive width of the responsive image always?
2 - How to make sure the div (data) sticks at the bottom of the image always for different device dimensions?

I was messing around with `top:400px` but I cannot get it right, and `width` should actually always be 100% namely the width of the image but still my div sticks out way too much...

```css
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
}

.data {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #FFF;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 400px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image"><img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div>

      <div class="tag">
        <a href="#">TAG</a>
      </div>

      <div class="title">
        <a href="#">title</a>
      </div>

      <div class="data">
        <div class="date">
          01012001

          <div class="author">
            Author
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understand u right... so, your issue is:

1. Div .data must be always 100% width over the image?
2. Div .data must be always at bottom on the imate?

So check that:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* This can be inline too */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.image .data {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        
        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
      
        <div class="data">
          <div class="date">
            01012001

            <div class="author">
              Author
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tag">
        <a href="#">TAG</a>
      </div>

      <div class="title">
        <a href="#">title</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Some advices- try to group css styles. Use better selectors. Try to use all HTML 5 tags- for example, image can be wrapped with figure tag and the .data element- can be just figurecaption.

Good luck!